# Stuck with new test_install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

When I try the command "rails new test_install" on the windows console, it says this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\

C:\>rails new test_install 

       exist
   identical  README.rdoc
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru  
   identical  .gitignore  
   identical  Gemfile  
       exist  app  
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js  
identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css     
identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb  
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb  
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb  
   identical  app/assets/images/.keep  
   identical  app/mailers/.keep  
   identical  app/models/.keep  
   identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep  
   identical  app/models/concerns/.keep  
       exist  bin  
   identical  bin/bundle  
   identical  bin/rails  
   identical  bin/rake  
   identical  bin/setup  
       exist  config  
   identical  config/routes.rb  
   identical  config/application.rb  
   identical  config/environment.rb  
    conflict  config/secrets.yml  
Overwrite C:/test_install/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a  
       force  config/secrets.yml  
       exist  config/environments  
   identical  config/environments/development.rb  
   identical  config/environments/production.rb  
   identical  config/environments/test.rb  
       exist  config/initializers  
   identical  config/initializers/assets.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb  
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb  
       exist  config/locales  
   identical  config/locales/en.yml  
   identical  config/boot.rb  
   identical  config/database.yml  
       exist  db  
   identical  db/seeds.rb  
       exist  lib  
       exist  lib/tasks  
   identical  lib/tasks/.keep  
       exist  lib/assets  
   identical  lib/assets/.keep  
       exist  log  
   identical  log/.keep  
       exist  public  
   identical  public/404.html  
   identical  public/422.html  
   identical  public/500.html  
   identical  public/favicon.ico  
   identical  public/robots.txt  
       exist  test/fixtures  
   identical  test/fixtures/.keep  
       exist  test/controllers  
   identical  test/controllers/.keep  
       exist  test/mailers  
   identical  test/mailers/.keep  
       exist  test/models  
   identical  test/models/.keep  
       exist  test/helpers  
   identical  test/helpers/.keep  
       exist  test/integration  
   identical  test/integration/.keep  
   identical  test/test_helper.rb  
       exist  tmp/cache  
       exist  tmp/cache/assets  
       exist  vendor/assets/javascripts  
   identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep  
       exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets  
   identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep  
         run  bundle install  
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<mod
ule:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be
set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:
17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:10
:in `<module:Readline>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:8:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `<top (required)>
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel
_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2
/exe/bundle:16:in `<main>'

ruby -v  
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

rails -v  
Rails 4.2.5.1

git --version   
1.9.4.msysgit.2
```

When installing RailsInstaller I marked a box "Add executables for Ruby, DevKit and Git to the PATH" but it failed to that. What directories should I copy paste to change the environment variable path? Or the problem its something else?

Thanks

Comment: Does your username on that PC include non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I just googled and found these two that seem to have the same error as you - have you tried those solutions yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543273/error-when-making-a-new-rails-app   https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/415

What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the non-ASCII characters. Thanks to both of you|